# Can't find solution for 'npm run dev' error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, npm, laravel-mix

I just installed fresh laravel project and wanted to use laravel-mix. I writed command 'npm install'; 'npm install cross-env', but then when I write command 'npm run dev', it shows errors.

I was looking for solution on internet, but nothing works for me.

Already did 'npm cache clean --force', 'npm install --global cross-env'. This is my first day when trying something with npm.

```
npm version: 6.4.1 
node version: v10.14.2 
os: windows 10


This what shows up in command line: https://pastebin.com/ChuEstZS
These ar log files: https://pastebin.com/AxijkMEr https://pastebin.com/14PJxgpD
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Try `npm install -g yarn`

Comment: `npm install -g yarn` worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for my problem was `npm install -g yarn`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the problem on my side. I reset all node files.

`rm package.json`
`rm package-lock.json`
`rm -rf node_modules`
`npm cache clear --force`

After that run `npm install again`. Everything should be fine now.
Or you can remove the above files manually from the explorer. Because the above commnads are for Linux or gi bash